# MySQL InnoDB Corruption - but database has been dropped

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, data-corruption

It seems that startup is failing due to corruption in a database that we have already dropped.

MySQL is not starting, and the log shows the following error (a few hundred):
170905  5:46:05  InnoDB: Error: page 1 log sequence number 87166865838
and the DB could be corrupt and to see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

As suggested, we started MySQL with innodb_force_recovery = 2 and innodb_purge_threads = 0, backed up the databases, and then dropped the database with the corrupted table(s).

MySQL still does not start. The error log ASCII/HEX dump shows segments of data that was in the deleted database.

Why are we still having problems with the deleted database? It feels like a process is still hanging, or something might not have deleted properly.

Any ideas? Thanks

Using MySQL 5.5.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: "Deleted"?  Via `DROP DATABASE`?  Was there a crash recently?

Comment: Yes that is correct - DROP DATABASE. There was a DDOS attack on the server, and afterwards, MySQL would not start. It still doesn't start without force recovery, even though the database/tables it complains about is gone.

Comment: What else does it say in the log file?